# Try to apply try_resources wuth compile errors

Tags: java

I'm trying to apply a `try_resources`:

```java
    public ReferenceGroup forEach(ZipEntryConsumer zipEntryConsumer) {
        ReferenceGroup referenceGroup = null;
        try (InputStream s3ResourceInputStream = this.s3Resource.getInputStream(); ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(s3ResourceInputStream)) {
                LocalFileHeader localFileHeader;
                while ((localFileHeader = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    Path path = Paths.get(localFileHeader.getFileName());
                    boolean isDirectory = localFileHeader.isDirectory();

                    referenceGroup = zipEntryConsumer.accept(zipInputStream, path, isDirectory);
                }
        }

        return referenceGroup;
    }
```

However, I'm getting:

```
 │     Unhandled exception type IOException thrown by automatic close() invocation on s3ResourceInputStream Java (16778098) [28, 20]
 │     Unhandled exception type IOException Java (16777384) [28, 44]
 │     Unhandled exception type IOException thrown by automatic close() invocation on zipInputStream Java (16778098) [28, 93]
 │     Unhandled exception type IOException Java (16777384) [30, 31]
```

I don't quite figure out what I'm doung wrong, any ideas?

Comment: you need to add `catch (IOException)` to the `try`, or a `try-catch`, or `throws IOException` to the method -- `InputStream.close()` and `ZipInputStream.close()` both are declared to throw an `IOException` - a checked Exception that must be handled -- `close()` is called *automatically*  by try with resources